# $interval cancel angularjs not working

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, promise, intervals

I'm tring to call 2 functions, and each one cancel the other. I'm using ionic and angularjs $interval. This is my code:

```
    var promise;
var promise2;   
$scope.$on('mapInitialized', function(event, map) {
    var justLocation = window.localStorage.getItem('justLocation');
    var tracage      = window.localStorage.getItem('tracage');
    //Location defined function
    //traceDirection defined function
    if(justLocation==1){
        $interval.cancel(promise2);
        promise = $interval(Location, 5000);
    } else if(tracage==1) {
        $interval.cancel(promise);
        promise2 = $interval(traceDirection, 5000);     
    }
});
```

But when I'm running the code, the 2 function running at the same time, please any idea about my problem